# export to excel using existing excel template

Tags: export-to-excel

I have used Export to Excel Functionality as below:

```
var table = getReport(param1, param2, param3);
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Report.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView grd = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView();
            grd.DataSource = table; // give datasource here
            grd.DataBind();
            StringWriter swr = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter tw = new HtmlTextWriter(swr);
            grd.RenderControl(tw);
            Response.Write(swr.ToString());
            Response.End();
            return View();
```

where getReport returns data in table format.
Now this creates a new excel file but i want to use existing excel template to create excel output.
How to to add such template to project and how to bind data with it?

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are using now is writing an HTML string to the Response and setting the ContentType to Excel in the Response headers.  This does not create a true Excel file, it just forces the browser to launch the file in Excel, and Excel is able to handle HTML files. There is no way to add a template with this approach.

If you want to use an existing Excel file as a template, you will need to use an API that can create and modify real Excel files, such as [OfficeWriter](http://www.officewriter.com).  Here is an example of how to bind your DataTable directly to a template file using OfficeWriter.

```
using SoftArtisans.OfficeWriter.ExcelWriter;    

ExcelTemplate xlt = new ExcelTemplate(); 
//Open the template file
xlt.Open(pathToTemplateFile); 
//Create a DataBindingProperties object
DataBindingProperties props = xlt.CreateDataBindingProperties(); 
// Call the BindData method, passing the DataTable and a name for the datasource 
// which will be referenced in the "data markers" in the template
xlt.BindData(table, "DataSource1", props);
//Call the Process method, which binds the data and generates the output file
xlt.Process(); 
//Stream the file to the Response 
xlt.Save(Response, "Report.xls", false);
```

Disclaimer: I work for SoftArtisans, the makers of OfficeWriter